# google form data to php variables

Tags: java, php, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm using Google Forms to collect data from users and finally that data is storing inside Google spreadsheets.
Now, I would like to read that data immediately after submitting the form. Using Apps Script, is there any possibility to get data into variables and use them in my php ( or Java ) program. ?

Answer (score 0):

You could could build a webapp that delivers the data out to an html page and collect the data from there.